# Available options to extract a large number of triples from XML using TPE

Tags: marklogic

An initial task seems to be a quite simple:
there is a large xml file with such a structure

```
<batch id=1123>
<production>
<activity>DETTY9828RAW18COUNT     1     ID   1234   ACTIVE </activity>
<activity>DETTY9828RAW24COUNT     2     ID   0373   ACTIVE </activity>
<activity>RASSE0932RTT01COUNT    20     ID   9393   PASSIVE</activity>
....
</production>
</batch>
```

The total number of activity tags is about 1800000, each tag has some encoded structure inside the
contents.

The goal is to produce a set of corresponding triples given such file.
About 15000000 triples should be extracracted in the result.

I apply Marklogic TPE and define a template like that:

```
{
  template: {
    context:
      "/batch/production",
    pathNamespace: [{
      "prefix": "cts",
      "namespaceUri": "http://marklogic.com/cts",
    }],
    enabled: true,
    
    vars: [
      {
        name: 'prod',
        val: '"http://40ind.com/man/10/prod#"',
      },
      {
        "name":"rdf_type_iri",
        "val":"sem:iri('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type')"
      },
      ],

templates: [
  {
    context: "activity[fn:substring(./text(), 43, 6) eq 'ACTIVE']",
    vars:[
      {
        name: 'op',
        val: 'fn:normalize-space(fn:substring(./text(), 1, 8))',
      },
      ....
      ],
    triples:[
      ....
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
```

The tests with a small XML file give expected results.
However when I start loading of the actual XML file, since a two or three minutes
I get the error message:   XDMP-INMMTRPLFULL: In-memory triple storage full;

Because MarkLogic prohibits increase of 'Memory Triple Index Size' more than up to 512 Mb,
I made an attempt to separate the nested template and defined separate templates for odd and even
activities:

```
templates: [
  {
    context: "activity[fn:substring(./text(), 43, 6) eq 'ACTIVE' and position() mod 2 = 1 ]",
    ...
  },
  {
    context: "activity[fn:substring(./text(), 43, 6) eq 'ACTIVE' and position() mod 2 = 0 ]",
    ...
  }
 ]
   ...
```

I expected, that (1) Marklogic will apply two templates in parallel threads, and (2) after finishing each template the triples will be flushed from the in-memory index.

However, in reality I see that a single thread is used (Docker Desktop does not show increase of
CPU cores for the Marklogic container), and the same error XDMP-INMMTRPLFULL is raised.

So, which options are available for me to set the  Memory Triple Index Size above 512 Mb and
implement parallel TPE processing ?

Comment: Please explain (1) how many activity fragments are in a batch document and (2) what method you are using to ingest.  One item to understand upfront is that TDE is just an indexing layer on a document. There is no separate thread per template or context.  Alos good to note is that MarkLogic is not designed to handle huge amounts of XML in a single document.

Comment: In general I expect 1800000 activity fragments (XML tags), each activity is described by a structure of 6 fields (encoded in a string).

To ingest the XML file I currently use X-Query xdmp:document-load function. For production I am going to use mlcp. From your remarks can I expect that using of mlcp will enable multithreading processing ?